# How can I convert an Integer array with length m to an array with length n in Java

Tags: java, processing

Hey want to convert an Integer array from a given length (bigger than 852) to an other Integer array of a lengh of 852.

That's because I want to display m values to 852 pixels.

The logic way is just to devide the ratio betwwen those two:

Let's say the array I want to compress has 2556 values.

The ratio between that is 2556/852 = 3, so I could jsut grab the 3 values and make the average.

The problem is that not allways the ratio is an integer, for example 2756/852 is 3.2347...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be one of programming, but of algorithm. What do you want to do? Think it through on paper. And I suggest you use smaller numbers so you can fully write out the samples. How can you spread 5 values into 2 slots? What would make sense? What are the pros and cons of each approach? In the end you're approximating and you *will* lose information, so the question is really *what kind* of information are you more okay with losing.

Comment: "The problem is that not allways the ratio is an integer, for example 2756/852 is 3.2347..."  So figure out how many times 852 goes EVENLY into 2756 using INTEGER DIVISION (which should occur already if both operands are of integer type).  Then use the MOD (%) operator to figure out how many LEFTOVERS there are.  Now you have the "base number" of items to average, plus how many of the first X groups need an additional one item added to it (based on the leftovers number).

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved, I manage to create a function int Java that does exacly what I want. You just need to import `import java.util.Arrays;`

The function is `compressArr(arrayToCompress, newArrayLength)`

Returns a float array.

```
public static float[] compressArr(float[] arr1, int l){
float[] arr2 = new float[l];
for(int i = 0; i<l;i++){
arr2[i] = average(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr1,P1(i,arr1.length,l),P2(i,arr1.length,l)+1));
}
  return arr2;
}

public static int P1(int x,int n, int d){
  float r = ((float)n)/d;
  int b = 0;
  int p = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<x ; i++){
p = (int)(x*r-b);
b*=p;
}
return(p);
}

public static int P2(int x,int n, int d){
  x+=1;
  float r = ((float)n)/d;
  int b = 0;
  int p = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<x ; i++){
p = (int)(x*r-b);
b*=p;
}
return(p-1);
}

static float average(float a[]) {
  int n = a.length;
  float sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  sum += a[i];
  return sum / n;
}
```